# jsonPath - problem with accessing to field by index

Tags: json, web, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I trying access to value `Carrier` by taking value from `shipping_id`. I testing queries at https://www.jsonquerytool.com/. If I type key by hand `$.shipping_methods["11"]` or `$.shipping_methods.11`I receive correct result `["Carrier"]`. But I have problem with taking key value from `shipping_id` field. I was trying with many variations of this `$.shipping_methods[$.shipping_id]` but without success. It's possible with pure jsonPath?

```
{
   "shipping_id":"11",
   "shipping_methods":{
      "10":"Post",
      "11":"Carrier"
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Consider upvoting/accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the JSON-Path implementation/environment you are using this may or may not be possible. This is because the feature you are asking for is not of the [proposed standard](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), though some libraries have features that enable queries like that, e.g. in [JSONPath-Plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath) you could use `@property` and `@parent` (I had no success using `@root`) - but those are 'extensions':

```
$.shipping_methods[?(@property == @parent.shipping_id)]
```

You can test this [online here](https://jsonpath.com/).

The page you have linked is using [JSPath](https://github.com/dfilatov/jspath) under the hood, and I cannot see any of the required features mentioned in the readme.  It would be simpler to drill down in a general programming language that hosts the JSON-Path engine but not sure if this is an option here.